# I am sending multiple file of form to server but it show error like this

Tags: javascript, php

I am sending multiple file of form to server but it show error like this:-
[image: description]

```html
 $post_params['files'][] = 
              '@'            . $this->fields['files']['tmp_name'][$index]
              . ';filename=' . $this->fields['files']['name'][$index]
              . ';type='     . $this->fields['files']['type'][$index];
          }
  
  //print_r($post_params); die;
          // We send XML via CURL using POST with a http header of text/xml.
          $url = "http://54.221.28.145:8080/kv_image_rest_service/rest/files/upload";
          $ch = curl_init($url);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: multipart/form-data'));
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_params);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 0);
          curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
          $ch_result = curl_exec($ch);
          curl_close($ch);
          // Print CURL result.
          echo $ch_result;
```

Comment: while sending URL via `curl` make sure you encode first i.e `urlencode()`

Comment: Please, copy/paste error message in post instead of giving picture

Comment: "Bad Request, no files present in request."